# POST Request is Displaying as GET Request During Replay In Jmeter

Tags: post, get, jmeter

I have a Jmeter script where during replay, Post request is displaying as Get request and the parameters in the request are not sent to the server. Due to this, correlations are failing at this request.

One of the parameters in the request is ViewState with so many characters. Is this large parameter value causing the above issue? How to proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're sending a malformed request therefore instead of properly responding to a POST request you're being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) somewhere (most probably to Login page)

Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in `HTML` or `Browser` mode to see what page you're hitting in the reality

[image]

With regards to the ViewState, "so many characters" is not a problem, the problem is that these are not random characters. ViewState is being used for [client-side state management](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/) and if you fail to provide the proper value you won't be able to move further so you need to design your test as follows:

1. Open first page

- Extract ViewState using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

2. Open second page

- here you need to pass viewstate from the step 1 along with other parameters

More information: [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan

Answer (score 0):

What I'm able to understand is the request may be getting redirected. This happens usually when the server expects a unique request. If you recorded the request, you may be possibly using older headers that carry old cookie information. Check your headers and then reconstruct the request.

Make sure you are not using old cookies anywhere. remove that cookie part from HTTP Header Manager everywhere.